# Axios multiple Requests in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create 2 requests and set variables with `this.setState({})` for further changes.

This is what i got:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {user: false, repository :false}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.all([
    axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/antranilan'),
    axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/antranilan/repos')
    ])
    .then(axios.spread(function (userResponse, reposResponse) {
            this.setState({user : userResponse.data, repository : reposResponse.data});
        });
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
     <div> 
      {this.state.user.login}
      {this.state.repository.length}
     </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I looked up through multiple questions with what i am trying to do but there was no solution to what i am trying to achive.

Comment: `.then(axios.spread` that looks wrong, because `.then` traditionally expects a function as an argument, not the result of calling a function

Comment: How should it look like?

Comment: looks like axios.all and axios.spread won't be around too long anyway, https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/1042

Comment: @JaromandaX I believe the problem is with loosing context inside callback.

Comment: yes, you are 100% correct @YuryTarabanko - the axios.spread and axios.all issue will become a problem for the OP eventually

Comment: This is way harder than it should. I tried to use XMLHttpRequest before in loop and now axios is being a problem. I had hint of using Promise.all but i am not sure how to use it.

Comment: it's in the answer ... and the answer to your previous question didn't even bother with axios - not sure what was wrong with that answer

Comment: @Mac "axios is being a problem" actully axios does its job (promisifying network operations) The idea is that `axios.all` and `axios.spread` helpers might be removed in future versions because there is native analog supported by major envs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have binding issue in your code.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // You should use object to delineate the type
    this.state = {user: {}, repository :{} }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Better use native Promise.all
    Promise.all([
      axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/antranilan'),
      axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/antranilan/repos')
    ])
    // use arrow function to avoid loosing context
    // BTW you don't need to use axios.spread with ES2015 destructuring
    .then(([userResponse, reposResponse]) => {
            this.setState({user : userResponse.data, repository : reposResponse.data});
        });
  }
 
  render() {
    const { user, repository } = this.state
    return (
     <div> 
      {user && user.login}
      {repository && repository.length}
     </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**UPDATE** as @JaromandaX pointed out you'd better stick with native `Promise.all` and destructuring.

Comment: I'd recommend `Promise.all` instead of `axios.all` ... seems axios.all is destined for the trash - https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/1042