# Combine api get on HandleSubmit in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using axios get in a react App.

This url returns results:

```
/api/search/occupation/Doctor
```

and this returns results as well

```
/api/search/gender/male
```

How can I **combine** the two ?

Here is my handle submit:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { get } from 'axios'
...
...


  handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault()
get(`/api/search/gender/${this.state.formValues.gender}`)
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res.data)
  if (res.status === 200) {
    this.setState({
      data: res.data
    })
  }
})


}
```

**Update**

I tried to get one response but get RefereceError

```
      handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.all([
      axios.get(`/api/search/gender/${this.state.formValues.gender}`),
      axios.get(`/api/search/occupation/${this.state.formValues.occupation}`)
    ])
    .then(axios.spread(function (gender, religion) {
      var genderData = gender.data || []
      var occupationData = occupation.data || []
      var userData = genderData.concat(occupationData)
      that.setState({ userData: userData })
    }))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

Comment: You can chain the requests, `axios.get('api1']).then(response => {
    axios.get('api2').then(response => {`

Comment: If you need to make 2 requests in parallel, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45795257/5709697

Comment: @Just Code .. I think chaining will give me one response . Correct ? Or will my response be two like the answer below? I would appreciate if you post this as an answer with bit more details. Thanks

Comment: @StarAzure Ofcourse chaining will give you two response, but first lets understand why you need to chain the requests, as answer posted seems to be correct and you seems to be trying to achieve different.

Answer (score 3):

You can send both the request in parallel and then update the state once both of the request has been resolved.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
 const promise1= axios.get('api1');
 const promise2= axios.get('api2');
 Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(response => {
   // Update the state using response[0] and response[1]
 })
}
```

Also note that if the second API request depend on the response of first API request, then you cannot use `Promise.all`

Comment: This answer is very clear and I was sure will work. I am not getting any results though. Does promise.all work as an "And" condition ? Basically both my api calls are made to the same database - Api1 - gets users with Occupation=Doctor and Api2 - Further refines by getting users with gender=Female.

Comment: get(`/api/search/gender/${this.state.formValues.gender}`) - This  give me results --- But     Promise.all([
      get(`/api/search/gender/${this.state.formValues.gender}`)
    ]) does not... I will add next api call to promise.all after one works

Comment: I had console.log(res.data[0].username) .. When I changed res[0] I get result. So now how do I combine res[0] and res[1] ? I was hoping to get just one combined response with combined results of the two calls.. This is for a search form so need a consolidated result of /gender and /occupation calls..

Comment: I'm not marking this as accepted because it gives me two responses .. res[0] and res[1].. thanks though as it is close.